# UltraEdit Current Line Highlight

Tags: text-editor, ultraedit

The line with the cursor in it is highlighted with a pale, aquamarine color.

Is there a configuration method to change that color?

Is there a configuration method to turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's version is < 20, open in menu View - Set Colors... and turn off Enable Active Line Coloring.

Answer (score 2):

For UltraEdit 20, you can change this in View > Themes > Manage Themes and uncheck the 'Enable Active Line Highlighting' option.

Answer (score 0):

For users of version 23: The Theme Manager now resides under the "Layout" tab of the ribbon. Like the version 20 solution, select Themes > Manage Themes, then de-select the checkbox for "Enable active line highlighting."